# The Free Boundary SABR: Natural Extension to Negative Rates

Tags: implied-volatility, stochastic-volatility, volatility-smile, sabr, sabr-model

In the paper by [Antonov, Konikov and Spector](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2557046)
An alternative approximation for the SABR model is presented. 
I'm interested to implement the formula for the ATM swaptions implied volatilities in the non-zero correlation case, that is based on mimicking the heat kernel expansion for small-time options.
$$dF_t=\sigma F_tdW_t \\ \text{volatility expansion} \sigma=\sigma_0+\sigma_1 T \\
\sigma_0=\gamma\frac{|\ln \frac{K}{F_0}|}{s_{\text{min}}} \\
\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_0}=\frac{\ln(K^\beta\sqrt{\nu_0\nu_{\text{min}}})-A_{\text{min}}-\ln\sigma_0-\frac{1}{2}\ln(KF_0)}{\frac{s_{\text{min}}^2}{\gamma^2}}$$
Proceeding in this direction, they derive the SABR ZC using new specified parameters $\tilde{\gamma}$ and $\tilde{\beta}$, to arrive at the first ATM correction expressed by:
$$\frac{\tilde{v}_0^{(1)}}{\tilde{v}_0^{(0)}}\bigg|_{K=F_0}=\frac{1}{12}\left(1-\frac{\tilde{\gamma}^2}{\gamma^2}-\frac{3}{2}\rho^2\right)\gamma^2+\frac{1}{4}\beta\rho\nu_0\gamma F_0^{\beta-1}.$$
How can one use this ATM correction to compute the ATM implied volatility?